# Python: How to generate list of every possible permutation of three characters given a length?

Tags: python, python-2.7, iteration

Say I have a string "ABC"

I'd like to iterate over every possibility of the characters 'A', 'B' and 'C' in a string 5 characters long.

**Desired output:**

```
['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A' ]
['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B' ]
...
['C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C' ]
```

I tried using `[x for x in itertools.permutations('ABC', r=5)`] but it just returns an empty list.

Answer (score 4):

You need [*itertools.product*](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) :

```
>>> list(product('ABC',repeat=5))
[('A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A'), ('A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B'), ('A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'C'), ('A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'A'), ('A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B'), ('A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'C'), ('A', 'A', 'A', 'C', 'A'), ('A', 'A', 'A', 'C', 'B'), ('A', 'A', 'A', 'C', 'C'), ('A', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'A'), ('A', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B'), ('A', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'C'), ('A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'A'), ('A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B'), ('A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C'), ('A', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A'), ('A', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'B'), ('A', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'C'), ('A', 'A', 'C', 'A', 'A'), ('A', 'A', 'C', 'A', 'B'), ('A', 'A', 'C', 'A', 'C'), ('A', 'A', 'C', 'B', 'A'), ('A', 'A', 'C', 'B', 'B'), ('A', 'A', 'C', 'B', 'C'), ('A', 'A', 'C', 'C', 'A'), ('A', 'A', 'C', 'C', 'B'), ('A', 'A', 'C', 'C', 'C'), ('A', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'A'), ('A', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'B'), ('A', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'C'), ('A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A'), ('A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'B'), ('A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'C'), ('A', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'A'), ('A', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'B'), ('A', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'C'), ('A', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'A'), ('A', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'B'), ('A', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'C'), ('A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'A'), ('A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B'), ('A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C'), ('A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'A'), ('A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'B'), ('A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C'), ('A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'A'), ('A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B'), ('A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'C'), ('A', 'B', 'C', 'B', 'A'), ('A', 'B', 'C', 'B', 'B'), ('A', 'B', 'C', 'B', 'C'), ('A', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'A'), ('A', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'B'), ('A', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C'), ('A', 'C', 'A', 'A', 'A'), ('A', 'C', 'A', 'A', 'B'), ('A', 'C', 'A', 'A', 'C'), ('A', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'A'), ('A', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'B'), ('A', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C'), ('A', 'C', 'A', 'C', 'A'), ('A', 'C', 'A', 'C', 'B'), ('A', 'C', 'A', 'C', 'C'), ('A', 'C', 'B', 'A', 'A'), ('A', 'C', 'B', 'A', 'B'), ('A', 'C', 'B', 'A', 'C'), ('A', 'C', 'B', 'B', 'A'), ('A', 'C', 'B', 'B', 'B'), ('A', 'C', 'B', 'B', 'C'), ('A', 'C', 'B', 'C', 'A'), ('A', 'C', 'B', 'C', 'B'), ('A', 'C', 'B', 'C', 'C'), ('A', 'C', 'C', 'A', 'A'), ('A', 'C', 'C', 'A', 'B'), ('A', 'C', 'C', 'A', 'C'), ('A', 'C', 'C', 'B', 'A'), ('A', 'C', 'C', 'B', 'B'), ('A', 'C', 'C', 'B', 'C'), ('A', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'A'), ('A', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'B'), ('A', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C'), ('B', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A'), ('B', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B'), ('B', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'C'), ('B', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'A'), ('B', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B'), ('B', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'C'), ('B', 'A', 'A', 'C', 'A'), ('B', 'A', 'A', 'C', 'B'), ('B', 'A', 'A', 'C', 'C'), ('B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'A'), ('B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B'), ('B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'C'), ('B', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'A'), ('B', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B'), ('B', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C'), ('B', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A'), ('B', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'B'), ('B', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'C'), ('B', 'A', 'C', 'A', 'A'), ('B', 'A', 'C', 'A', 'B'), ('B', 'A', 'C', 'A', 'C'), ('B', 'A', 'C', 'B', 'A'), ('B', 'A', 'C', 'B', 'B'), ('B', 'A', 'C', 'B', 'C'), ('B', 'A', 'C', 'C', 'A'), ('B', 'A', 'C', 'C', 'B'), ('B', 'A', 'C', 'C', 'C'), ('B', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'A'), ('B', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'B'), ('B', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'C'), ('B', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A'), ('B', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'B'), ('B', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'C'), ('B', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'A'), ('B', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'B'), ('B', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'C'), ('B', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'A'), ('B', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'B'), ('B', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'C'), ('B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'A'), ('B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B'), ('B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C'), ('B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'A'), ('B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'B'), ('B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C'), ('B', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'A'), ('B', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B'), ('B', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'C'), ('B', 'B', 'C', 'B', 'A'), ('B', 'B', 'C', 'B', 'B'), ('B', 'B', 'C', 'B', 'C'), ('B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'A'), ('B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'B'), ('B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C'), ('B', 'C', 'A', 'A', 'A'), ('B', 'C', 'A', 'A', 'B'), ('B', 'C', 'A', 'A', 'C'), ('B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'A'), ('B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'B'), ('B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C'), ('B', 'C', 'A', 'C', 'A'), ('B', 'C', 'A', 'C', 'B'), ('B', 'C', 'A', 'C', 'C'), ('B', 'C', 'B', 'A', 'A'), ('B', 'C', 'B', 'A', 'B'), ('B', 'C', 'B', 'A', 'C'), ('B', 'C', 'B', 'B', 'A'), ('B', 'C', 'B', 'B', 'B'), ('B', 'C', 'B', 'B', 'C'), ('B', 'C', 'B', 'C', 'A'), ('B', 'C', 'B', 'C', 'B'), ('B', 'C', 'B', 'C', 'C'), ('B', 'C', 'C', 'A', 'A'), ('B', 'C', 'C', 'A', 'B'), ('B', 'C', 'C', 'A', 'C'), ('B', 'C', 'C', 'B', 'A'), ('B', 'C', 'C', 'B', 'B'), ('B', 'C', 'C', 'B', 'C'), ('B', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'A'), ('B', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'B'), ('B', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C'), ('C', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A'), ('C', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B'), ('C', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'C'), ('C', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'A'), ('C', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B'), ('C', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'C'), ('C', 'A', 'A', 'C', 'A'), ('C', 'A', 'A', 'C', 'B'), ('C', 'A', 'A', 'C', 'C'), ('C', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'A'), ('C', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B'), ('C', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'C'), ('C', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'A'), ('C', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B'), ('C', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C'), ('C', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A'), ('C', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'B'), ('C', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'C'), ('C', 'A', 'C', 'A', 'A'), ('C', 'A', 'C', 'A', 'B'), ('C', 'A', 'C', 'A', 'C'), ('C', 'A', 'C', 'B', 'A'), ('C', 'A', 'C', 'B', 'B'), ('C', 'A', 'C', 'B', 'C'), ('C', 'A', 'C', 'C', 'A'), ('C', 'A', 'C', 'C', 'B'), ('C', 'A', 'C', 'C', 'C'), ('C', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'A'), ('C', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'B'), ('C', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'C'), ('C', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A'), ('C', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'B'), ('C', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'C'), ('C', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'A'), ('C', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'B'), ('C', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'C'), ('C', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'A'), ('C', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'B'), ('C', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'C'), ('C', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'A'), ('C', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B'), ('C', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C'), ('C', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'A'), ('C', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'B'), ('C', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C'), ('C', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'A'), ('C', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B'), ('C', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'C'), ('C', 'B', 'C', 'B', 'A'), ('C', 'B', 'C', 'B', 'B'), ('C', 'B', 'C', 'B', 'C'), ('C', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'A'), ('C', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'B'), ('C', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C'), ('C', 'C', 'A', 'A', 'A'), ('C', 'C', 'A', 'A', 'B'), ('C', 'C', 'A', 'A', 'C'), ('C', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'A'), ('C', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'B'), ('C', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C'), ('C', 'C', 'A', 'C', 'A'), ('C', 'C', 'A', 'C', 'B'), ('C', 'C', 'A', 'C', 'C'), ('C', 'C', 'B', 'A', 'A'), ('C', 'C', 'B', 'A', 'B'), ('C', 'C', 'B', 'A', 'C'), ('C', 'C', 'B', 'B', 'A'), ('C', 'C', 'B', 'B', 'B'), ('C', 'C', 'B', 'B', 'C'), ('C', 'C', 'B', 'C', 'A'), ('C', 'C', 'B', 'C', 'B'), ('C', 'C', 'B', 'C', 'C'), ('C', 'C', 'C', 'A', 'A'), ('C', 'C', 'C', 'A', 'B'), ('C', 'C', 'C', 'A', 'C'), ('C', 'C', 'C', 'B', 'A'), ('C', 'C', 'C', 'B', 'B'), ('C', 'C', 'C', 'B', 'C'), ('C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'A'), ('C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'B'), ('C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C')]
```